# NavigationBar is not showing

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have embedded some ViewControllers in a `UINavigationController` But the backButton/navigationBar is not showing. In the second `ViewController` the navigationBar is shoving in StoryBoard, but not appearing in simulator, and in the third `ViewController` the navigationBar is not showing at all. Why is this happening?

[image]

***EDIT***

I use `prepareForSegue` to send data to the next `ViewController`. I don't know if that matters..

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToListVCSegue", sender: self)

    }   


 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
        {
            if segue.identifier == "ToListVCSegue"
            {

                let destination = segue.destination as! ListLocationViewController
                if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                  destination.listID = listID[indexPath.row]

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check options on the Inspector view for your navigation controller and all view controllers pushed on it.
[image: navigation controller options]

[image: view controller options]

Comment: That did the trick for the third `ViewController` in the Storyboard, but it still isn´t showing in the simulator

Comment: @PerNil How do you instantiate your storyboard? Can you post the code please?

Comment: I'm using Firebase, and are using autologin. So that took me past the `UINAvigationController` and directly to the first `UITableViewController`. Tat was the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You probably connect thirdViewController with the secondViewController with a Storyboard Segue. Select that segue and in the Attributes Inspector, change the Kind to 'Show (e.g. Push)'[image]

Comment: All segues are of type `Show (e.g. Push)`